# Don't argparse read unicode from commandline?

Tags: python, unicode, argparse

Running Python 2.7

When executing:

```
$ python client.py get_emails -a "åäö"
```

I get:

```
usage: client.py get_emails [-h] [-a AREA] [-t {rfc2822,plain}]
client.py get_emails: error: argument -a/--area: invalid unicode value: '\xc3\xa5\xc3\xa4\xc3\xb6'
```

This is my parser:

```
def _argparse():
    desc = """
           Simple CLI-client for...
           """
    argparser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description=desc)
    subparsers = argparser.add_subparsers(dest='command')

    # create the parser for the "get_emails" command
    parser_get_emails = subparsers.add_parser('get_emails', help=u'Get email list')
    parser_get_emails.add_argument('-a', '--area', type=unicode, help='Limit to area')
    parser_get_emails.add_argument('-t', '--out_type', choices=['rfc2822', 'plain'],
                                   default='rfc2822', help='Type of output')

    args = argparser.parse_args()
    return args
```

Does this mean I can't use any unicode characters with python argparse module?

Comment: What is the encoding of your terminal?

Comment: Your terminal uses UTF-8 encoding, but Python uses ASCII by default, so `unicode` is using the wrong encoding to convert the bytes to a `unicode` object.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You can try

```
type=lambda s: unicode(s, 'utf8')
```

instead of

```
type=unicode
```

Without encoding argument unicode() defaults to ascii.

Comment: Great, I will test it tomorrow when in front of the computer again. Was thinking along the lines to use `lambda s: unicode(s, locale.getdefaultlocale()[1])` I suppose that would be more flexible. Any caveats?

Comment: @NiclasNilsson: getdefaultlocale can return None,None under circumstances, so you're going to need a fallback, like `getdefaultlocale()[1] or 'utf8'`

Comment: the encoding may be different. Use `sys.getfilesystemencoding()` instead of hardcoding `utf8` here.

Comment: Is that more safe then locale.getdefaultlocale()[1] ?

Comment: @NiclasNilsson: I have little experience with non-unicode consoles, but [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4012571/python-which-encoding-is-used-for-processing-sys-argv) people say that `getfilesystemencoding` is not the argv encoding. It _might_ be `sys.stdin.encoding` though.

Comment: @georg: I don't see `sys.getfilesystemencoding()` mentioned in the link you provided. Why do you think `sys.argv` items are not in `sys.getfilesystemencoding()`? There are issues with undecodable arguments but it is a different problem.

Answer (score 15):

The command-line arguments are encoded using `sys.getfilesystemencoding()`:

```
import sys

def commandline_arg(bytestring):
    unicode_string = bytestring.decode(sys.getfilesystemencoding())
    return unicode_string

# ...
parser_get_emails.add_argument('-a', '--area', type=commandline_arg)
```

Note: You don't need it in Python 3 (the arguments are already Unicode). It uses [`os.fsdecode()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.fsdecode) in this case because sometimes command-line arguments might be undecodable. See [PEP 383 -- Non-decodable Bytes in System Character Interfaces](http://legacy.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0383/).

Comment: the actual answer may be more complicated if you need to support filenames undecodable in the current local encoding (Unicode API on Windows, misconfigured locale on Linux). See more details in [Как работать с путями c русскими символами?](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/527872/23044) (ask if you need the translation)

Comment: This works for me. In my case the argument value is a string of Chinese characters. The accepted answer complains `invalid <lambda> value:`.