# How to input Polish characters into CMD as a Python parameter?

Tags: python, python-2.7, cmd, diacritics

I just started to learn coding in Python and I have a simple Python program that returns `Cześć <input>` where `<input>` is the name that a user can input into CMD as a parameter for this Python program. If no input is given it'll return `Cześć Świat`. It works fine, but when I for instance input the name `Łukasz` it strips the strike from the `Ł` and the program returns `Cześć Lukasz` instead of the correct `Cześć Łukasz`.

In Windows CMD I used the CD command to go to the folder containing the Python program and there I execute the Python program by using the statement: `hello.py Łukasz`.

My script looks like this (it is originally from Google's Python exercises ([source](https://developers.google.com/edu/python/set-up)) and I edited it to make it work for unicode characters with Python version 2.7 and also replaced 'hello' with 'cześć' for instance):

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

import sys

# Define a main() function that prints a little greeting.
    def main():
  # Get the name from the command line, using 'World' as a fallback.
  if len(sys.argv) >= 2:
    name = sys.argv[1].decode('cp1252')
  else:
    name = u'Świat'
  str = u'Cześć '+name
  print str.encode('utf-8')

# This is the standard boilerplate that calls the main() function.
if __name__ == '__main__':
  main()
```

Originally I decoded the `sys.argv[1]` with `utf-8`, but somehow when I used the letter `Óó` it would throw an ugly exception (see [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12468284/678650)). Using either `utf-8` or `cp1252` results in the Polish letters (e.g. ĄĆĘŁŃŚŻŹ) getting stripped of their accents, with the exception of the letter `Óó` which seems to keep their accent when using `cp1252`, because using that letter with `utf-8` caused the previously mentioned exception.

So my question is, how do I retrieve the string intact with the accents from CMD to use in my Python program?

**I won't accept answers that suggest to remove/ignore the accents!**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[This is a known limitation of Python 2 in Windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4012571/python-which-encoding-is-used-for-processing-sys-argv). `sys.argv` does not accept Unicode and characters are truncated to the standard ANSI character page. Upgrading to Python 3 will solve your issue.

Comment: Wow... Python 3 doesn't even need `u'some string'` and the decode/encode anymore, it just accepts that I'm using diacritics! Thank you :)